# JavaScript setTime() with Call back VS. with anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I found the following two examples of setTime function, although the code looks the same, the result is different in the two cases.

Example1: Result "Hello Stack Overflow"

```
var a = "world";  
setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello " + a)}, 2000);  
a = "Stack Overflow";
```

Example2:  Result "Hello world"

```
function callback(a){  
    return function(){  
        alert("Hello " + a);  
    }  
}  
var a = "world";    
setTimeout(callback(a), 2000);    
a = "Stack Overflow";
```

Why in the first example the value of a changed, and in excample2 it didn't?

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, the function reads the value of `a` directly.  In the second example, the function reads the value of the parameter passed to it's factory function.  Even though we reassign the value of the variable later, that doesn't affect the value of the parameter.  It might be more clear if a different name is used for the parameter:

```
function callback(x){  
    return function(){  
        alert("Hello " + x);  
    }  
}  
var a = "world";    
setTimeout(callback(a), 2000);    
a = "Stack Overflow";
```

If you had used an object, you'd have a different story.  Modifying your examples slightly, these both have the same result:

Example 1

```
var o = {};
o.a = "world";
setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello " + o.a)}, 2000);  
o.a = "Stack Overflow";
```

Example 2

```
function callback(obj){  
    return function(){  
        alert("Hello " + obj.a);  
    }  
} 
var o = {};
o.a = "world";
setTimeout(callback(o), 2000);    
o.a = "Stack Overflow";
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing that the OP actually understands how and why closures work and why when they pass `callback(a)` as the parameter to setTimeout that it's actually executing the `callback` function _immediately_ and the it's the function being returned from the closure that is executing at the end of the setTimeout... that's probably another thread altogether.

That aside, nice answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't change in the second example because you are actually creating a new local variable `a` as the argument to the `callback` function.  So when you change the value of the global `a` it doesn't effect the value of the `a` inside that function.

- global var `a` points at the string "world"
- global var `a` gets passed to function
- local var `a` is created and set to the value of global var `a`
- global var `a` is set to a new value
- function later runs, and uses the value of local var `a`

So because function arguments have the semantics of local variables, you can't change it after the fact like this.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example `callback(a)` creates a closure which maintains the current value of `a` so when it executes after the specified timeout you see the old value.

You should read this [JavaScript Closure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

By invoking the `callback` function the initial value of `a` is copied (passed by value) and the returned function forms a closure,that is why it shows the initial value and not the latest value.

Answer (score 0):

The second one doesn't work as expected because you are *calling the function*, which makes it execute immediately, rather than passing it to setTimeout, where it will be executed after the specified time.

Comment: His function returns a function, so it should be fine.

Comment: @Squeegy Ah, didn't see that. My bad :/